# Google Sheets Query - Remove Blank Column Header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm running a simple Google Sheets Query like:

```
=query({input1!A2:D},"select Col1,' ','  ','   ',Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null",0)
```

I'm leaving blank columns which works great, but instead, I have a header like below appearing:

```
" "()   "  "()  "   "()
```

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove it by adding empty `label ' ''','  ''','   '''`

```
=QUERY({input1!A2:D}, "select Col1,' ','  ','   ',Col2,Col3 
                       where Col1 is not null
                       label ' ''','  ''','   '''", 0)
```